# Catching iframe display options in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

**Problem:** I'm trying to catch errors in iframe loading using Javascript. The solution needs to be able to pass in an error statement with a url to another function, since I need to be able to retrieve the url of the page on which the error occurs (not the original iframe 'src' attribute).

```
Refused to display '...' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

- I know that most people would immediately think this is impossible for browser "sameorigin" security policies, but I'm pretty sure there's some (hackety) workaround.
- Not sure if this will help, but Google Chrome displays the error message in the console.
- Can we catch all errors issued by the page, or overwrite the default error handler for a specific site?

Note: The page in the iframe is not on the same origin as its parent.

Comment: You cannot catch errors that occur in an iframe with a different origin.  Those errors are occurring in a different context which is not your parent page.

Comment: _“The page in the iframe is not on the same origin as its parent”_ – that means the Same Origin Policy will prevent you from knowing _anything_ about it.

Comment: I understand both of your comments. However, all I need to know is the url of the page in which an error occurs, or at least get some error message detailing information about the error. No, I do not need to know about the iframe's contents or `src`. I've tried setting `window.onerror`, but that didn't work either.